# Jquery scroll event triggers at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At http://www.mtjmedia.nl/Homepage/contact/ I have a simple jquery code that is supposed to make the big social icons appear/fade in if you're scrolling.
Instead, the three icons appear when you scroll only to the bottom of the page..
Does someone know what the problem is?

```
var $win = $(window);
var $img = $('.fadeInScroll');
$win.on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();

    $img.each(function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        var prev = $self.offset();
        if (prev) {
            var pt = 0;
            pt = prev.top - $win.height();
            $self.css({
                opacity: (scrollTop - pt) / ($self.offset().top - pt)
            });
        } else {
            $self.css({
                opacity: 1
            });
        }
    });

}).scroll();
```

I'm using this script: http://trulycode.com/bytes/simple-appear-on-scroll/

Answer (score 0):

Move your code inside of an on load function `$(function() { });` as shown below. It seems that the issue is caused by calling `var $win = $(window);` before the page is fully loaded

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
    var $win = $(window);
    var $img = $('.fadeInScroll');
    $win.on('scroll', function() {
        var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();

        $img.each(function() {
            var $self = $(this);
            var prev = $self.offset();
            if (prev) {
                var pt = 0;
                pt = prev.top - $win.height();
                $self.css({
                    opacity: (scrollTop - pt) / ($self.offset().top - pt)
                });
            } else {
                $self.css({
                    opacity: 1
                });
            }
        });

    }).scroll();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing the `window` object to the `document` object and by removing the `.scroll()` from the end of the event attachment, the code seems to be working fine.

Have a look at this jsfiddle that replicates your scenario, just scroll down in the preview panel to see the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/7kjj9z1c/2/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the .scroll() at the end of the method, like this example.

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  console.log('Action here');
});
```

Here a full-functional example. Hope this help.

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $('#number').html(parseInt($('#number').html())+1);
        });
    </script>
<style>
    body{
         height: 3000px;
    }

    span{
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
    }

    div.column{
        position:relative;
        height:2500px;
        width:30px;
        display:inline-block;
         background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
      background: -o-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
      background: linear-gradient(red, blue); /* Standard syntax */
    }

    #number{
        font-size:340px;
        position:fixed;
        left:100px;
        height: 40%;
        width:40%;
        display: inline-block;

    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <span>dO SCROLL:</span><br>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div id="number">0</div>



</body>
```

Every pixel you scroll would make trigger the event, and will increase the counter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Can you maybe explain further?
I have no knowlegde in javascript/jquery what so ever and would just like to properly integrate this script in my page.